# Return data from 2 pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have `products`, `categories`, `sizes` tables and also have 2 pivot tables named `category_product` and `product_size` in my database.
I am trying to get products belong to a specific category and I need to filter them by size.

I have tried this but I am getting all sizes...

```php
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$products = $category->products()
     ->with('sizes')
     ->whereHas('sizes', function($q) use($size_id) {
        $q->where('size_id', '=', $size_id);
     })
     ->paginate(12);
```

Product model

```php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}

public function sizes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class);
}
```

Category model

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Size model

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whereHas()` will filter the models returned *based on* the eager loaded relationship, but does not filter the relationship itself. If you want that, you need to pair it with the second argument of `with()` like so:

```php
$size_id  = 10;
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$products = $category
    ->products()
    ->with('sizes', fn ($q) => $q->where('size_id', $size_id))
    ->whereHas('sizes', fn ($q) => $q->where('size_id', $size_id))
    ->paginate(12);
```

So you are using the same callback twice, which is a bit silly but works to return only the desired data.